# Image from webcam preview throws generic GDI+ exception

Tags: c#, image, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk, microsoft-expression

I'm making a custom webcam user control.

I use Microsoft Expression Encoder, and set a PreviewWindow on a panel inside the control.

All's fine, except that when I try to grab the image, I get an exception:

> Generic GDI+ exception

My first try was:

```
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(p.Width, p.Width))
            {
                panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
                bmp.Save(@"c:\test.png");
            }
```

Another waS:

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(panelVideoPreview.Width, panelVideoPreview.Height))
          { 
              using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
              {
                  Rectangle rectanglePanelVideoPreview = panelVideoPreview.Bounds;

             Point sourcePoints = panelVideoPreview.PointToScreen(new Point(panelVideoPreview.ClientRectangle.X, panelVideoPreview.ClientRectangle.Y));
             g.CopyFromScreen(sourcePoints, Point.Empty, rectanglePanelVideoPreview.Size); 
              }

              string strGrabFileName = String.Format("C:\\Snapshot.jpg", DateTime.Now);
              bitmap.Save(strGrabFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Have you checked if there is enough space in c:\ drive or is writing to c:\ drive permitted(outside a folder).I Have encountered similar exceptions in such scenario

Comment: @techno I am ALMOST sure that the problem is in permissions. I can write to my App data folder. Is there a way to write to a custom folder (not C: but maybe inside my application execution folder) without setting permissions from Windows?

Comment: You can write in the application folder if it is not in c:\Program Files\

Comment: I've tried, but it seems not to work (using Application.StartupPath).

Comment: Try saving to the Temporary folder -Path.gettemppath();

Comment: I am trying something similar but I only get a blank image.  any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in writing the file.
There may not be enough space in c:\ drive or you do not have permission to write to c:\ drive(outside a folder).
Try writing to **AppData** ,if you want to write to c:\ drive,you need to acquire administrative privileges by using a custom manifest.